# How does the second variable work in "for i, j in enumerate" vs list[i]

Tags: python

I understand that it is for 'index', 'value' in enumerate, I thought that I could use the second variable as list[index] but it doesn't seem to work as such, I was wondering what the difference was.

```
codeCopy = [1,2,1,1]
currentSequence = [2,1,2,2]
correctColor = 0

for i, n in enumerate(codeCopy):
    for a, b in enumerate(currentSequence):
        if n == b:
            correctColor += 1
            n = None
            b = None
            print("i:",i, a)
            break
            
print(currentSequence)
print(codeCopy)
```

which outputs their original values instead of their new value of 'None' but if I replace

```
n = None
b = None
```

to

```
codeCopy[i] = None
currentSequence[a] = None
```

It turns them accordingly to 'None'

Comment: first variable is for index and second variable is the value at that index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which outputs their original values instead of their new value of 'none'

It's not supposed to do that. The values `n` and `b`, as returned by `enumerate`, are pointers to the objects, but setting them to `None` only changes what those variable names reference, rather than the actual object itself. (You'll have to use `memcpy`-type magic to achieve this.)

Think of it like this:

```py
>>> a = ['my', 'reference', 'to', 'a', 'list']
>>> b = a
>>> b[0] = 'this also changes a'  # b references the same object at a
>>> a
['this also changes a', 'reference', 'to', 'a', 'list']
>>> b = None  # this overwrites what b points to; it does not affect a
>>> a
['this also changes a', 'reference', 'to', 'a', 'list']
```

Suppose the program, in memory, looks like this:

```
address | value
100     | ['my', 'reference', 'to', 'a', 'list']  
101     | a -> 100 (list)
102     | b -> 100 (list)
```

When you change `b`, it doesn't actually affect the actual object:

```
address | value
100     | ['my', 'reference', 'to', 'a', 'list']  
101     | a -> 100 (list)
102     | b -> 103 (None)  # does NOT set the value at 100 to None
103     | None  # implementation detail: small integers and None and other things are permanently kept somewhere in memory at initialization
```

If you want to modify the value that's actually at the list, you need to do `the_list[desired_index] = None`.

Answer (score 0):

from
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

> Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def enumerate(sequence, start=0):
>     n = start
>     for elem in sequence:
>         yield n, elem
>         n += 1
> ```